# I have a sql table with only two columns, CODE and BALANCE, CODE is a name and Balance is a $ amount

Tags: php, sql

How come when i try to print_r inside of this echo and div class it returns patient owes 1?

```
 $balance_out = sql::results("SELECT CODE,BALANCE FROM event.acs.ptbalance() WHERE CODE='$patient_id' and BALANCE > 0");
    echo "<div class='patient_alert red'>Patient owes ".print_r($balance_out)."</div>";
```

But if i just print_r like this it gives me the array correctly.

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r ($balance_out); echo "</pre>";
```

like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CODE] => ACSSCHAR00
            [BALANCE] => 24.33
        )

)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Do i have to identify which array key value i want?

Comment: `print_r` is a function with a side effect: printing (echo). The return value is not a string, but just that 1.

Comment: Because reading manuals became... obsolete? Really, the php manual about this function tells you everything you have to know. Is it really that hard to read it?

Comment: You down voted me for asking a question?

Comment: @HeadWay No, for asking a question that shows no effort on your side (and yes, that includes reading the PHP manual entry for [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r)).

Comment: That's pretty lame, i understand what print_r did before asking the question, but i was confused on some aspects of print_r and why they were functioning like that. It seems absurd to down vote someone for asking a viable question. Apparently my question was that horrible that i got down voted twice. I guess it's more convenient to down vote anonymously for a question that some might feel is not worthy of their time; it's like being an elitist and secretive all at the same time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenate `print_r` into a string like you are attempting, unless you pass a second param of `true`

For example

```
print_r($balance_out, true);
```

Otherwise it returns true, which is interpreted by the string as `1`

You may need to do something like this however, if you want to insert the patient balance into your HTML output

```
 "<div class='patient_alert red'>Patient owes ".$balance_out[0]['BALANCE']."</div>";
```

Comment: Thank you, it is much more clear now as how it interprets. Although the example didn't work. Patient owes ".$balance_out['BALANCE']."

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad, I misread the array depth in your post, it would be `".$balance_out[0]['BALANCE']."`

Comment: Thanks again, if i may ask one more question, what is the [0] pertain to?

Answer (score 2):

Don't make assumptions about how functions work; just check [the manual](http://php.net/print_r):

> mixed print_r ( mixed $expression [, bool $return = false ] )
>   
> [...]
>   **Return Values**
>   
> [...]
>   When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, **the return value is TRUE**.

So if you want that print_r() returns the value rather than printing it, use the second parameter accordingly:

```
echo "<div class='patient_alert red'>Patient owes ".print_r($balance_out, true)."</div>";
                                                                          ^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful and good knowledge.

Comment: Sorry for another question, but now it prints like so:  Patient owes Array ( [0] => Array ( [BALANCE] => 24.33 ) )  how to i drop everything except the actual balance/numbers?  I tried to echo but it says array even if i drop CODE and only have BALANCE.

Comment: print_r is a DEBUG function, meant to spit out the structure/contents of an array. you're trying to subvert it into a general purpose output function, which **IT IS NOT AND NEVER HAS BEEN**. Use propert `print()` and `echo` calls.